# how to write array obj into file with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, writefile

I'm trying with this code below, I can write file on server and the file has content but, when I download the file, it's blank.

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream('./tmp/text.txt');

file.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err) });

rows.forEach(function(v) {
  file.write(v + "\r\n");

  productExport.DeleteProduct(v.ProductId, function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
  });
});

file.end();

var file = "./tmp/text.txt";
res.download(file); // Set disposition and send it.
```

How can I download the file with all the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing data to a file through I/O is an asynchronous operation. You have to wait for the WriteStream to complete before you can download the file.

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream('./tmp/text.txt');
file.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err) });
rows.forEach(function(v) {
    file.write(v + "\r\n");
    productExport.DeleteProduct(v.ProductId, function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
    });
});
file.end();
file.on('finish', function() {
    var file = "./tmp/text.txt";
    res.download(file); // Set disposition and send it.
});
```

Extra Information:

[FileSystem#createWriteStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) return WriteStream object.
From the document of [WriteStream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) it stats there are 6 events [close, drain, error, finish, pipe, unpipe].

in the node.js world, you should always expect to use callback or seek for complete/finish event when there are I/O operations.

Comment: thank you that's work, why you know file have event finish

Answer (score 3):

The way your code is structured is incorrect for what you're trying to do. Primarily, your issue is that you're responding with `res.download()` before the file stream is done being written to. Additionally, you have `var file` being initialized twice in the same scope, this isn't correct either.

```
var file = "./tmp/text.txt";
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(file);
writeStream.on('error', err => console.log );

writeStream.on('finish', () => {
    return res.download(file); // Set disposition and send it.
});

rows.forEach((v) => {
    writeStream.write(v + "\r\n");
    productExport.DeleteProduct(v.ProductId, function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
    });
});

writeStream.end();
```

If you're confused by this, and perhaps async processing in general, [this is the defacto answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for understanding async in Node.js

Comment: yes i know that asyns in node js but i don't know how to wait until the file finished. now i know that have the event finish in file